# replace string if length is less than x

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe below.

```
a = {'Id': ['ants', 'bees', 'cows', 'snakes', 'horses'], '2nd Attempts': [10, 12, 15, 14, 0],
     '3rd Attempts': [10, 10, 9, 11, 10]}
a = pd.DataFrame(a)
print (a)
```

I want to able add text ('-s') to anything which is equal to 4 characters. i have unsuccessfully tried the below. as it produces the error, ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
if a['Id'].str.len() == 3:
    a['Id'] = a['Id'].str.replace('s', '-s')
else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need `loc`, if need replace last `s` is necessary add `$`:

```
mask = a['Id'].str.len() == 4
a.loc[mask, 'Id'] = a.loc[mask, 'Id'].str.replace('s$', '-s')
print (a)
   2nd Attempts  3rd Attempts      Id
0            10            10   ant-s
1            12            10   bee-s
2            15             9   cow-s
3            14            11  snakes
4             0            10  horses
```

Solution with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
mask = a['Id'].str.len() == 4
a.Id = a.Id.mask(mask, a.Id.str.replace('s$', '-s'))
print (a)
   2nd Attempts  3rd Attempts      Id
0            10            10   ant-s
1            12            10   bee-s
2            15             9   cow-s
3            14            11  snakes
4             0            10  horses
```