# Python replace string with empty if length not equal to x

Tags: python, dataframe, replace, string-length

I have the following dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'ssn':[12345,54321,111,47895,222311],'Name':['john','mike','adam','doug','liz']})
```

The DataFrame contains a 'ssn' that is supposed to only contain 5 digits. I want to replace all the rows that contain less than or greater than 5 digits with blank spaces.

The desired output is as below:

```
   Name   ssn
0  john   12345
1  mike   54321
2  adam   
3  doug   47895
4  liz
```

I referred to the following post from SO [replace string if length is less than x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140060/replace-string-if-length-is-less-than-x)
However, on using the same solution with following commands gives me an error:

```
mask = df['ssn'].str.len() == 5
df['ssn'] = df['ssn'].mask(mask, df['ssn'].str.replace(df['ssn'], ''))
Traceback (most recent call last): 
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: `df.assign(ssn=df.ssn.where(df.ssn.astype(str).str.len().eq(5), ''))`.  You aren't dealing with strings, so I'm surprised you're getting that error, since it should error out when you try to use the string accessor

Comment: It works great! How do I accept your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column ssn contains numbers not string, that is why it is not working. Try the following :

```
mask = df['ssn'].astype(str).str.len() != 5
df.loc[mask, 'ssn'] = ''

In [1] : print(df)
Out[1] :    Name    ssn
0  john  12345
1  mike  54321
2  adam       
3  doug  47895
4   liz
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `df.apply` as well: `df['ssn'] = df['ssn'].apply(lambda a: a if len(str(a))==5 else '')`.